# help me with this UIsearch bar need to properly designed in my view

Tags: iphone

I need to have a properly designed my uisearchbar .

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125.0, 25.0, 150, 40)];
[searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

searchBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
searchBar.showsCancelButton=NO;
searchBar.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searchBar.autocapitalizationType   = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

In below picture show

i need to have only the oval part of search bar.

I dont want to have rectangle part of searchBar

What to do ?

Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use UISearchBar, then. The ...Bar part indicates that it's meant to be used as a "bar", similar to a navigation bar or tool bar. Instead, use UITextField with the borderStyle property set to UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect.